# Read first row from excel file and create mysql table with column1 fields

Tags: php, mysql, excel, xls

1) Input option to upload an excel file.

2) Read the excel file and according to its first row fields create table in the mysql database tabel automatically, i mean PHP script should create table.

3) Import excel file data to the database.

I tried the below code here i can read the excel file data and import it in the table. But its working only when the database table is already created in the database. I am looking to create the database table according to the excel file first column/header field automatically.
Any ideas.?

```
<?php  
//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("excel_database",$connect); //select the table 
// 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You can easily create a table based on the column names, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html the hard part is deciding what type of data should be in each DB column. If you know what kind of data to expect, it's easy. Otherwise you'll have to check the data in each column to make sure it's data will all conform with some data type you'll create in the DB ie.. varchar int... whatever.

Comment: @Bryan.. i'm not particular about the data type. Thank you!

Comment: @Bryan..I am looking for the script that creates the database table automatically according to the excel file (first row/header fields) when the excel file is uploaded..Thank you!

Comment: if you're not particular just use varchar for everything. You don't need a script, it's just one query to create the table, see the link in my first comment. take each column name and use it for the table field name and set them all to varchar(255) easy as pie.

Comment: @bryan.. ya i can create a table directly n easily but in general bosses don't agree what comes easy. Dats what im looking for a script. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quiet sure why you have to create a table every time you read a csv file.
I don't think it's a great idea to create a lot of tables since 
1.Hard to maintain.
2.Data from different upload is not associated.(so what's the point to move all data into database?)
3.When you have to get some data, can you remember which table to search?

Here is some solutions I've concerned:
1.You can use the same table and add a flag(uploaded time stamp,for instance) if you want to filter the data.
2.IF column name various from time to time you can just simply create a table with column (id,column1,column2...) and save the column name each time as well.
3.IF you just want to save and download the excel data and don't want to search or sort it with your program, you can just simply save the file in a folder and save the folder path in the database.

IF you really , really want to create table each time you read a file, you may try something below:

Suppose your csv file looks like this:

```
table_name,column_name_1,column_name_2,...,column_name_n
table_name,column_data_1,column_data_2,...,column_data_n
table_name,column_data_1,column_data_2,...,column_data_n
...
```

you can do something like this:

```
$table_name = ''; // get the table name
$data = array(); // data array
$column_name = array(); // get the column names
$column_len = array(); //Decide the column length for the table when you create it
do {
    if ($file_line[0]) { 
        if(empty($table_name)){
            $table_name = $file_line[0];// get the table name
        }
        $column_num = count($file_line);//the number of columns

        for($i = 1;$i<$column_num;$i++){

            if(empty($column_name[$i])){
                $column_name[$i] = $file_line[$i]; // get the column name array
            }
            //get the max length for each column
            if(empty($column_len[$i]) || count($file_line[$i]) > $column_len[$i]){
                $column_len = count($file_line[$i]);
            }
            $data_line[$i] = $file_line[$i];
        }
    } 
} while ($file_line = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

//create the table
$create_query = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} IF NOT EXISTS(\n";
$create_query .= " id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,\n"
foreach ($column_name as $key => $name){
    $create_query .= " {$name} VARCHAR({$column_len[$key]}) ,\n"
}
$create_query .= " PRIMARY KEY (id)\n);";
// Output the create_query should shows something like this:
// CREATE TABLE table_name IF NOT EXISTS(
// id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
// column_name_1 VARCHAR(1000),
// column_name_2 VARCHAR(500),
// ...
// PRIMARY KEY (id)
// );
mysql_query($create_query);
//insert data(you have already worked this out so you can just ignore this part)
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} VALUES \n";
$insert_array = array();
foreach($data as $line){
    $line_str = implode(',',$line);
    $insert_array []= "(NULL,{$line_str})";
}
$insert_query .= implode(",\n",$insert_array);
$insert_query .= ";";
mysql_query($insert_query);
```